# Best structure for Process Host of a WorkflowApplication - WF 4.5

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I'm using Windows Workflow and am hosting a Process host in a normal C# Class file which is used by WCF classes (hosted in IIS).  The host is not hosted as a service, it is a normal class.  I've read lots of articles and looked at many example and created my class accordingly.  It seems to work perfectly in a single user test situation but fails occassionally in multi-user situations.  Please can you advise if I'm on the right track or doing something fundamentally wrong?  Thanks.

Below is my code:

```
public sealed class PurchaseRequisitionProcessHost : IPurchaseRequisitionProcessHost
{
    public event PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle;
    public delegate void PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler(PurchaseRequisitionWorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e);
    private static volatile PurchaseRequisitionProcessHost _instance = null;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private AutoResetEvent instanceUnloaded = null;

    public static PurchaseRequisitionProcessHost Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
                lock(syncRoot)
                {

                    if(_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new PurchaseRequisitionProcessHost();
                    }
                }
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private PurchaseRequisitionProcessHost()
    {

    }

    protected void OnPurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle(PurchaseRequisitionWorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make a temporary copy of the event to avoid possibility of
        // a race condition if the last subscriber unsubscribes
        // immediately after the null check and before the event is raised.
        PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler handler = PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle;

        // Event will be null if there are no subscribers
        if(handler != null)
        {
            // Use the () operator to raise the event.
            handler(e);
        }
    }

    // executed when instance goes idle
    public void OnIdle(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
    {
        PurchaseRequisitionWorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs args = new PurchaseRequisitionWorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs();

        if(e.Bookmarks != null && e.Bookmarks.Any())
        {
            args.BookMarkName = e.Bookmarks[0].BookmarkName;

            string prNumber = args.BookMarkName.Substring(args.BookMarkName.IndexOf("_") + 1);
            prNumber = prNumber.Substring(0, prNumber.IndexOf("_"));

            args.PrNumber = prNumber;
        }

        args.InstanceId = e.InstanceId;

        PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle(args);
    }

    public PersistableIdleAction OnIdleAndPersistable(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
    {
        return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
    }

    public void OnWorkFlowUnload(WorkflowApplicationEventArgs e)
    {
        CleanUpSubscribedEvents();
        instanceUnloaded.Set();
    }

    //// executed when instance has completed
    public void OnWorkflowCompleted(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        CleanUpSubscribedEvents();
        instanceUnloaded.Set();
    }

    //// executed when instance has aborted
    public void OnWorkflowAborted(WorkflowApplicationAbortedEventArgs e)
    {
        CleanUpSubscribedEvents();
        instanceUnloaded.Set();
    }

    // executed when unhandled exception
    public UnhandledExceptionAction OnWorkflowUnhandledException(WorkflowApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Helpers.Common.Common.logger.Error(string.Format("Unhandled WorkflowException for instance {0}", e.InstanceId), e.UnhandledException);
        CleanUpSubscribedEvents();
        instanceUnloaded.Set();

        return UnhandledExceptionAction.Terminate;
    }

    private void CleanUpSubscribedEvents()
    {
        if(PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle != null)
        {
            Delegate[] clientList = PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle.GetInvocationList();

            if(clientList != null && clientList.Any())
            {
                foreach(Delegate d in clientList)
                {
                    PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle -= (d as PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #region IPurchaseRequisitionProcessHost Members

    public WorkflowApplication CreateAndRun(PurchaseRequisition pr, string uploadsPath)
    {
        return CreateAndRun(pr, uploadsPath, null);
    }

    // creates a workflow application, binds parameters, links extensions and run it
    public WorkflowApplication CreateAndRun(PurchaseRequisition pr, string uploadsPath, PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler idleDelegate)
    {
        WorkflowApplication instance = null;

        try
        {
            instanceUnloaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            using(var instanceStore = new DisposableStore())
            {
                // input parameters for the WF program
                IDictionary<string, object> inputs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                inputs.Add("PurchaseRequisition", pr);
                inputs.Add("UploadsPath", uploadsPath);

                instance = new WorkflowApplication(new PurchaseRequisitionProcessWorkflow(), inputs);
                instance.InstanceStore = instanceStore.Store;

                // Add the custom tracking participant 
                instance.Extensions.Add(new CustomTrackingParticipant());

                instance.PersistableIdle += OnIdleAndPersistable;

                instance.Completed += OnWorkflowCompleted;
                instance.Unloaded += OnWorkFlowUnload;
                instance.Aborted += OnWorkflowAborted;
                instance.OnUnhandledException += OnWorkflowUnhandledException;
                instance.Idle += OnIdle;

                if(idleDelegate != null)
                {
                    PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle -= idleDelegate;
                    PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle += idleDelegate;
                }

                // continue executing this instance
                instance.Run();

                instanceUnloaded.WaitOne();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.Common.Common.logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public BookmarkResumptionResult SubmitApprovalDecision(Guid instanceId, string prNumber, string approvalSource, bool approved)
    {
        return SubmitApprovalDecision(instanceId, prNumber, approvalSource, approved, null);
    }

    public BookmarkResumptionResult SubmitApprovalDecision(Guid instanceId, string prNumber, string approvalSource, bool approved, PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler idleDelegate)
    {
        BookmarkResumptionResult brr = BookmarkResumptionResult.NotReady;

        WorkflowApplication instance = this.LoadInstance(instanceId, idleDelegate);

        string bookmarkName = string.Format("Pr_{0}_waitingForApprovalFrom_{1}", prNumber, approvalSource);

        if(instance != null && instance.GetBookmarks().Count > 0)
        {
            brr = instance.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, approved);

        }

        instanceUnloaded.WaitOne();

        return brr;
    }

    public BookmarkResumptionResult ReceiptPrGoods(Guid instanceId, PurchaseRequisitionReceipt pr)
    {
        return ReceiptPrGoods(instanceId, pr, null);
    }

    public BookmarkResumptionResult ReceiptPrGoods(Guid instanceId, PurchaseRequisitionReceipt pr, PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler idleDelegate)
    {
        BookmarkResumptionResult brr = BookmarkResumptionResult.NotReady;

        WorkflowApplication instance = this.LoadInstance(instanceId, idleDelegate);

        string bookmarkName = string.Format("Pr_{0}_waitingForReceiptOfGoods", pr.PrNumber);

        if(instance != null && instance.GetBookmarks().Count > 0)
        {
            brr = instance.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, pr);
        }

        instanceUnloaded.WaitOne();

        return brr;
    }

    public void UnsubscribePurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEvent(PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler idleDelegate)
    {
        PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle -= idleDelegate;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IProcessHost Members

    // returns true if the instance is waiting (has pending bookmarks)
    public bool IsInstanceWaiting(Guid instanceId)
    {
        bool isWaiting = false;

        WorkflowApplication instance = LoadInstance(instanceId);

        if(instance != null)
        {
            isWaiting = instance.GetBookmarks().Count > 0;
        }

        return isWaiting;
    }

    public WorkflowApplication LoadInstance(Guid instanceId)
    {
        return LoadInstance(instanceId, null);
    }

    // load and resume a workflow instance. If the instance is in memory, 
    // will return the version from memory. If not, will load it from the 
    // persistent store
    public WorkflowApplication LoadInstance(Guid instanceId, PurchaseRequisitionWfIdleEventHandler idleDelegate)
    {
        WorkflowApplication instance = null;

        try
        {
            instanceUnloaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            using(var instanceStore = new DisposableStore())
            {
                instance = new WorkflowApplication(new PurchaseRequisitionProcessWorkflow());
                WorkflowApplicationInstance wfAppInstance = WorkflowApplication.GetInstance(instanceId, instanceStore.Store);

                // Add the custom tracking participant 
                instance.Extensions.Add(new CustomTrackingParticipant());

                instance.PersistableIdle += OnIdleAndPersistable;
                instance.Completed += OnWorkflowCompleted;
                instance.Unloaded += OnWorkFlowUnload;
                instance.Aborted += OnWorkflowAborted;
                instance.OnUnhandledException += OnWorkflowUnhandledException;
                instance.Idle += OnIdle;

                if(idleDelegate != null)
                {
                    PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle -= idleDelegate;
                    PurchaseRequisitionWf_Idle += idleDelegate;
                }

                try
                {
                    instance.Load(wfAppInstance);
                }
                catch(InstanceOwnerException)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.Common.Common.logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    #endregion

}

public class PurchaseRequisitionWorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string PrNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Guid InstanceId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string BookMarkName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class DisposableStore : IDisposable
{
    private string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.SqlPersistenceStoreDbConnectionString;
    private SqlWorkflowInstanceStore _Store = null;
    private InstanceHandle _handle = null;

    public SqlWorkflowInstanceStore Store
    {
        get
        {
            if(_Store == null)
            {
                _Store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(connectionString);
                _Store.HostLockRenewalPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                _Store.MaxConnectionRetries = 25;
                _Store.RunnableInstancesDetectionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                _Store.InstanceCompletionAction = InstanceCompletionAction.DeleteAll;
                _Store.InstanceLockedExceptionAction = InstanceLockedExceptionAction.BasicRetry;

                _handle = _Store.CreateInstanceHandle();
                CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand createOwnerCmd = new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand();
                InstanceView view = _Store.Execute(_handle, createOwnerCmd, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                _Store.DefaultInstanceOwner = view.InstanceOwner;
            }

            return _Store;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _handle.Free();
        _handle = _Store.CreateInstanceHandle(_Store.DefaultInstanceOwner);

        try
        {
            _Store.Execute(_handle, new DeleteWorkflowOwnerCommand(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        catch(InstancePersistenceCommandException ex)
        {
            Helpers.Common.Common.logger.Info(ex.Message);
        }
        catch(InstanceOwnerException ex)
        {
            Helpers.Common.Common.logger.Info(ex.Message);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            Helpers.Common.Common.logger.Info(ex.Message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.Common.Common.logger.Info(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            _handle.Free();
            _Store.DefaultInstanceOwner = null;
            _handle = null;
            _Store = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the value in making your own hosting for IIS, why didn't you build your workflow as workflow service (XAMLX) that can be hosted directly in IIS without custom host?

Comment: This workflow is part of an assembly which has the hosting code and is referenced by a WCF service project.  The WCF service is hosted in IIS and initiates the workflow.  I suppose if I architected the solution differently, I could have the workflow as an individual service and the WCF service calling it.